# React-Native pinch-to-zoom using PanResponder

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, mobile

I have made a component to make `Image` zoom in a `View` component. I want to make pinch-to-zoom on Image. I am using `PanResponder` is there any way to get multitouch events?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do it with `PanResponder`, you can simply check whether there's one or two touches objects in the `event` property:

```
this.panResponder = PanResponder.create({
    onMoveShouldSetResponderCapture: () => true,
    onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture: () => true,

    onPanResponderGrant: (event, gestureState) => {

    },

    onPanResponderMove: (event, gestureState) => {
        const touches = event.nativeEvent.touches;

        if (touches.length >= 2) {
            // We have a pinch-to-zoom movement
            // Track locationX/locationY to know by how much the user moved their fingers
        } else {
            // We have a regular scroll movement
        }
    },

    onPanResponderRelease: (event, gestureState) => {

    },
});
```

Note that in `onPanResponderGrant` there may be one touch object, but then on `onPanResponderMove` there might be two, if the user pressed the second finger afterwards.

So take this into account - i.e. always check in `onPanResponderMove`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend looking at the [react-native-transformable-image](https://github.com/ldn0x7dc/react-native-transformable-image) library, or the lower-level [react-native-view-transformer](https://github.com/ldn0x7dc/react-native-view-transformer) component, which the former uses internally.

These may be useful to you as-is, or if you are looking to implement something more custom, reading their source code may be helpful in arriving at a solution.