# With PanResponder how do determine the starting point of each finger?

Tags: react-native, panresponder

Related to [React-Native pinch-to-zoom using PanResponder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45953982/react-native-pinch-to-zoom-using-panresponder)

I am trying to figure out how do I determine the starting point of multiple fingers?

For example:

1. finger 1 touches the screen and pans around (meaning a gesture handler is already triggered)
2. finger 2 comes in and starts to pan around too
3. finger 3 comes in and starts to pan around too

So if I had two fingers on the screen I want to know where each finger is.  The onMove gesture state only specifes the last moved finger but not the actual finger that was moved.

The use case I wanted to handle is basically a "who goes first" type app where multiple people touch the screen each of them represented as a different colored circle and after 3 seconds of not moving it will make one circle fill up the entire screen.